# UTF8 Bug in Chrome and Safari? Or wrong Apache setup?

Tags: php, apache, browser, webkit, google-chrome

So, this page: http://utf8test.n.ceromedia.dk/ has some UTF8 Characters. They display correctly in Firefox, IE and Opera, but doesn't work in Chrome and Safari. Boxes appear instead.

I have  and when I look at the headers: Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8

Can you see what's wrong? Is it something I do wrong, or is this a Webkit bug? I can't believe it.

Comment: I don't see a cool smiley even in the Firefox. The boxes with character codes instead. I guess it can be supported font issue

Comment: Aren't those characters in the title UTF8 too? They appear to be displaying fine even in Chrome. Could this be a font-issue? Not sure.

Comment: First of all, you didn't select a font, so the page will be displayed using the browser's default font(s). But even when I select DejaVu Sans Mono in Chrome, the smiley isn't displayed correctly, whereas in Emacs the smiley is visible as it should. DejaVu obviously has no `&#x07F7;` glyph (the thing after "Another UTF8 character"), so it isn't rendered at all.

Comment: Now I added this CSS: font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;

The problem is, the characters still doesn't render correct in Chrome

Comment: FYI, I uploaded three screenshots, all made under Linux: FF 3.6: http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4045/4412854241_26e17c24f8_o.png Chromium 5.0.307.11: http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2693/4412854275_8ba81541e0_o.png GNU Emacs 23.1.1: http://farm5.static.flickr.com/4001/4412854297_fb0653dfbc_o.png Not shown here, but conspicuous was that in FF, the title bar only showed ⎝⎠, but in Chromium, the title in the tab bar was drawn correctly (but is in Linux drawn using the default Fontconfig/Freetype2 libraries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I sorted it out. Apparently, the characters weren't correct UTF8. Now I copy/pasted some special characters from charmap (selected arial as font) and now it works.

Comment: Confirmed, the test page works for me in Firefox and Chrome now.